# xamarin.android [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

Tags: xamarin, manifest

I am developing an App with Google Maps and I have some difficulties in making it run on a Genymotion Emulator (Nexus 5 API 22)

**Here's the message I got :**

> Installing application on device
>       Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install output:            pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.companyname.progettocomputergraphics-Signed.apk
>       Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]
>       Deployment failed. Internal error.

**and thats my android manifest:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"   package="com.companyname.progettocomputergraphics">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <permission android:name="com.companyname.progettocomputergraphics.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="progettocomputergraphics" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gsm.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my_API_Key" />
        <service android:name=".ItineraryService"></service>
        <receiver android:name=".RoutesRecevier" />
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity">
            <intent-filler>
                <category android:name="android.intnet.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filler>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".InfoActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="MapActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same issue (in my case using  App Center Push SDK).

The issue was solved by **avoiding uppercase** on first letter of application/package name.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I will try to modify  uses-permission tag:

```
<permission android: name = "com.companyname.progettocomputergraphics.MAPS_RECEIVE" android: ProtectionLevel = "signature" />
```

Comment: Do you use Xamarin, yes? Try here paste the generated Manifest which can be found atprojectName \ obj \ Debug \ android \

Comment: Ok, done but I'm still getting this error: Warning: No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-08-22) or after any future revocation date.

Comment: I do not know. For that create new question on SO (and before it try find it on this site or others).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBFdb7p_3FTSQWX-sfOniZmQrsBHnM0Bu.."/>
```

in manifest